# Eclipse 4.3 Kepler missing JRE system library

Tags: eclipse, osx-mountain-lion, java

I am extremely new to java (about one week of experience at the moment). I have made a fair amount of simple programs in an older version of eclipse Juno on a PC. I copied all of the files onto a flash drive and put them into the workspace of eclipse kepler on my mac laptop. Now every single line of code is unrecognized and the JRE system library folder is gone from all of the projects. I am not sure how to fix this and I would love if someone will help my noob self at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the jre from your mac in eclipse. You find it under window preferences and search for jre.
After that, in your eclipse project you can use the new configured jre (project properties - Java Build Path)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this does help a bit, but could you elaborate on what I do in the preferences window to fix it? Sorry, bear with me here, I'm quite new at this :P

Comment: To configure the jre go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE (Add-Button) To Change the JRE-Libs in your Projekt: Right Click on you project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Tab Libraries. Select your JRE-System Lib and click edit - then you can select alternate jre ...