# How to make a play framework based project into a eclipse project in a better form?

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I am using play framework 1.2.4,and also trying 2.2.1.

In 1.2.4,I created a new play framework based project by using

> play new wonder

then I entered its directory,and ran this command

> play eclipsify

It was done successfully.And I imported it to eclipse,it worked,but was not pretty good,you will see why

(I am new here,and I don't have 10 reputation to post images,so I post images to another website,link is follow)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Lf0.jpg

(Here is another screenshot that shows the result of what I have done in Ubuntu 12.04 with play-2.2.1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVsPe.jpg
)

The related jars were just listed in the root directory,and it was so long.

First,how can I make it not list in that way?

Second,as what you see,these jars were linked to this project rather than copied to the sub-directory of this project.

If I want to make them copied to the sub-directory of this project when generating eclipse project,what should I do?

ps:
When I trying 2.2.1,there are not much different.If you know how to do in any one of these 2 versions,just tell me,thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't open your image, need to have an account at weibo.
If it's no matter for you to use playframework v.1 or v.2, it's better to use v.2 - it's just newest version.
Try to check if you are doing everuthing like described here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/IDE Pay attention at how do you import project into eclipse after play eclipsify.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what the issue is. This phrase is not very clear: "The related jars were just listed in the root directory,and it was so long." If you have access to http://imgur.com/ please post your screenshots there.

Comment: @FernandoCorreia :Thanks for replying.I've post my screenshot to imgur.com,and the description of this question has been modified correspondingly.

Comment: @arbuzz  : Thanks for replying.I did that exactly following what the official documentation told me.But it just ... I've post my screenshot to another site that you may access so that you may know what happened to me.Now I just want the list of jars being short.As for "copy all linked jars to sub-directory of that project",I think I should not want that.

Comment: @Scheung The screenshot made the issue more clear. In order for us to be able to help you more I suggest you follow @arbuzz's suggestion and mine and do it with Play 2.2.1 instead of Play 1.x. Then update your question showing the results of each of these commands: `play help` (to show the version); `play new myapp`; `cd myapp`; `play eclipse`; `ls -la` (on Linux) or `dir /b` (on Windows); import project on Eclipse and update screenshot.

Comment: @FernandoCorreia Thanks for replying again!I've tried it in Ubuntu with the newest version of play framework and its screenshot are here : http://i.imgur.com/zkDTtvY.png .And I've tried   <code> play "eclipse with-source=true"  </code>  ,then I had waited for a pretty long time.What it had done seemed to be downloading some jars from some servers and some of them were failed to download.And I don't known what this command exactly is used for.(I known it does nothing with this long list of linked jars,I just want to figure it out by the way.)

Comment: @FernandoCorreia I am so sorry that I haven't see your reply carefully.Now I have tried those several commands and results are posted here http://imgur.com/a/xagRV . And these are screenshots of them respectively, "play help" : http://imgur.com/OXjUOnj  "play new myapp" : http://imgur.com/E6BaFeN "cd myapp ; ll" : http://imgur.com/filpkMM  "play eclipse" : http://imgur.com/ko3L6sc  "ls -la" : http://imgur.com/o9dEWzb , finally,import it to eclipse : http://imgur.com/jviLt6R

Comment: @Scheung Thank you for your patience and cooperation. Your screenshots look good (except for the last one, showing the problem in Eclipse). I believe now I know what's going on: your Eclipse IDE is probably not yet configured for Play/Scala projects. I'll update my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Instructions for importing a new Play Java project into Eclipse, tested with Play Framework 2.2.1 and Eclipse Standard 4.3.1:

1. Download and install [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).
2. Create a new Play project. When asked, select the Java language:

   ```
   $ play new myapp
   ```
3. Change to the new application's directory:

   ```
   $ cd myapp
   ```
4. Generate the Eclipse project:

   - Without including library source code:

     ```
     $ play eclipse
     ```
   - Including library source code (may take a long time for downloads and a few sources might be missing):

     ```
     $ play "eclipse with-source=true"
     ```
5. Import the project into your Eclipse Workspace with `File | Import | General | Existing Projects into Workspace`.

Result:

[image: Play project imported into Eclipse]

For more information see [Setting up your preferred IDE](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE).

Comment: Thanks for help. I 've seen the official documentation,but it doesn't work in the way I expect.What happened were just like what I've described in the question.After seeing your answer,I've tryed those 2 commands,but they resulted the same just like the problem I've met before.Are there any comman else that can generate it into a eclipse project with all linked jars copied ?

Comment: Updated instructions.

Comment: Forgive my uncleared description.I am using JAVA and knowning nothing about Scala. Is it OK to choose Scala while I intend to develope a Java project?

Comment: I downloaded a new, unmodified Eclipse distribution, created a new Java project with play new and imported it into Eclipse. Please follow the instructions above, paying attention to the tested Eclipse version (4.3.1) and for the way the project must be imported ("Existing Projects into Workspace"). If it still doesn't work, I suspect it's an issue with Eclipse in your environment, and not with Play, so you'll need assistance from someone that is more used to debug issues with Eclipse.

Comment: OK~Thanks for your patience and kindness . I've been using Play for serveral months.During this period I've reinstalled my operating systems for serveral times , too , including windows and Ubuntu.And I also clear my whole hard disk and reinstalled all my operating systems once just a week ago.And All my software were also been reinstalled again .

Comment: On the other hand,I have been always using "Existing Projects into Workspace" to import java project because I haven't really heard another way to import and never thought about trying(Now I realized my unwisdom,I think I really try to know more about it).So,maybe there is an issue with Eclipse in my environment is the conclusion.And thank you for following this question !

Comment: And please forgive my poor English.I hope it doesn't make you confused.If it does,I feel apologetic.^_^

Comment: Another possibility: With the project open, open the Windows | Preferences dialog and click on Java | Installed JREs. Please verify that there is a JRE selected. If not, follow [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17385027/376366) to set it.

Comment: @FernandoCorreia How can I directly run my project from eclipse, I set the main class to `javassist.tools.rmi.AppletServer` and add `9000` port but I got Bad Request error on `localhost:9000`!

Comment: @NullPointer I don't know how to do that. I usually run the application from the command line and if needed I connect Eclipse to it to debug. I suggest you open a separate question for this.

Comment: Hello, 'play eclipse' command not found in Max os X, what i do ??

Answer (score 1):

Well, the post is answered already but **these commands are not supported in new versions of play.**
For users who are using new versions of play, here is the step by step guide for creation and import of play project in eclipse:

```
**Prerequisites:** java 1.8
```

type in terminal

```
java -version
```

to check if java is installed.
you should see something like:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

If it is not present then you can download from here: `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html` To Create a new application using SBT you must have sbt 0.13.13 or higher installed (download from here `https://www.scala-sbt.org/`)
open terminal and type following command to generate java project.

```
 sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

if you are on windows platform use sbt.bat instead of sbt

```
 sbt.bat new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

[image]

[image]

use following command for a scala project:

```
 sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
 sbt.bat  new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
```

After that, use

```
sbt run
```

and then go to `http://localhost:9000` to see the running server.
Now, you have successfully created your scala or java project.
Next step is importing it to an IDE. Lets' import it to eclipse. If your project contain mixed code java + scala then you have to download scala ide plugin to you eclipse. open eclipse -> Help ->Install new software -> click Add -> Add repository
Name: scala ide
Location : http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e47/scala212/stable/site
click Add.

[image]

After successfully adding the scala ide add following dependency  in your project/plugins.sbt file.

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.2")
```

You must compile your project before running the eclipse command. You can force compilation to happen when the eclipse command is run by adding the following setting in build.sbt:

```
// Compile the project before generating Eclipse files, so that generated .scala or .class files for views and routes are present
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile, compile in Test)
```

After compilation of project go to your project folder and type

```
 $sbt eclipse
```

The plug-in generates the two files Eclipse needs, the .classpath and .project files.

Once these files are generated, go to Eclipse and follow the usual steps to import a project into the Eclipse workspace: File → Import → Existing Projects into Workspace. Your project will then appear in the Eclipse Navigator, Project Explorer, Package Explorer, and other views.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you got the answer of this question or not, for all those people who will face similar issue, after following all step given on official documentation, still i face same issue described in question, solution is that you need to open **Scala perspective** in eclipse by default it is J2EE

Comment: I have not fixed it.And I was using J2EE.

Comment: Change perspective from J2EE to Scala, everything will work fine